What's difference between systemctl reboot and sudo reboot
What is the difference between systemctl reboot and sudo reboot in Ubuntu? What does systemctl reboot do that normal reboot don't?

Great question.
Systemctl :
systemctl is the command to interface with systemd, the init system used by modern Ubuntu releases (since 15.04). When you run systemctl reboot, it sends a command to systemd to perform a clean and orderly reboot of the system. So the risk of bricking softwares is also too lower
Sudo reboot compared to normal reboot :
The reboot command is a traditional Unix command that has been available for a long time. When prefixed with sudo, it has the necessary permissions to reboot the system.
But in new Ubuntu releases reboot and systemctl are linked
Also When a single user is logged in, sudo isn't necessary. When more than one user is logged in then sudo is required.
Applications can inhibit shutdown and reboot. You override these inhibitions with sudo.
A single user logged in via ssh still requires sudo.

Thank you for full explanation.

On systemd-based systems, isn't the reboot command (/usr/sbin/reboot) a symbolic link to systemctl anyhow?

See my comment above.

The answer is not correct, so should not be accepted.

user1885034 accepted it, I edited my answer  and it's more explained now, is there still anything wrong?
